# Print out the highest score

Tags: java, methods, display

Here is my main method, I won't include all the rest of the code as it is not necessary. However, I am trying to figure out how to print out the highest score out of the three variables: `player1`, `player2`, `player3`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Price is Right!");

    System.out.println("Player 1 are you ready to spin?");
    int player1 = player();
    System.out.println("Player 1 Your final score is: " + player1);

    System.out.println("Player 2 are you ready to spin?");
    int player2 = player();
    System.out.println("Player 2 Your final score is: " + player2);

    System.out.println("Player 3 are you ready to spin?");
    int player3 = player();
    System.out.println("Player 3 Your final score is: " + player3);

    // todo..
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I have thought about calling in a method to calculate this or using if statements, I am not sure what is the best approach.

Comment: And? How did it go with the `if` statements or the method call? What were the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: `int maxScore = IntStream.of(player1, player2, player3).max();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49951736/4298200), but much simpler, using an `int[]` array. We store the `maxScore` and the corresponding `maxUser` as we go, so we can output them at the end:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Price is Right!");
    int[] scores = new int[3];
    int maxScore = -1;
    int maxUser = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " are you ready to spin?");
        scores[i] = player();
        if (scores[i] > maxScore) {
            maxUser = i;
            maxScore = scores[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " Your final score is: " + scores[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Player " + (maxUser+1) + " won with a final score of " + maxScore);
}
```

Comment: This HELPED ME SO SO MUCH!! Thank you so much for your time and for helping me understand what to do, I appreciate your efforts greatly.

Comment: @HaleyNewbold also please consider all good answers, so people coming here in the future will find good answers quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is using if and else statements:

```
  if(Player1> Player2 && Playe1 > Player3){
        System.out.println("Highest score was earned by Player 1 which is"+ player1);
  }else if(Player2> Player3 && Playe2 > Player1){
        System.out.println("Highest score was earned by Player 2 which is"+ player2);  
  }else{
        System.out.println("Highest score was earned by Player 3 which is"+ player3);
         }
```

Comment: Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. As you will see, your code is not properly [intented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262).  Also read [this article](https://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](https://$SITEURL$/help) on how to write good answers. Better answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can put all player's scores in an array and then find highest amongst them

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores.put(player1.getScore());
scores.put(player2.getScore());
int highest = Collections.max(arrayList);
System.out.println("Highest score is: " + highest);
```

OR you can simply do it via `IF-Else`

Comment: `List<Integer> scores = List.of(player1, player2, player3);` Nice onliner. Also: `player1` is of type `int`. You won't be able to call `.getScore()` on it..

Comment: Yes you are right that you cannot call `.getScore()`  on  `int` type. But I just gave her an idea considering Player as a  `class`

Comment: Looking at the problem OP is trying to solve, I don't think that she has enough understanding to create custom classes (yet alone to infer from a compiler error that this what you have meant while not saying so)

Answer (score 0):

How about this very compact and easily extendable solution? Your teacher would be proud! If it is too complex take a look at [my other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49951938/4298200), which only uses an `int[]`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Price is Right!");
    int playerCount = 3;
    List<Integer> scores = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " are you ready to spin?");
        scores.add(player());
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " Your final score is: " + scores.get(scores.size()-1));
    }

    System.out.println("The maximum score is " + Collections.max(scores));
}
```

Instead of storing each player score in its own variable, we just collect them all in a `Collection`. By doing it this way we can simply change `playerCount` to accommodate any number of players!

And if you want to print *which* player won you can replace the last line with this:

```
int maxScore = Collections.max(scores);

for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
    if (scores.get(i) == maxScore) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " won with a final score of " + maxScore);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be (very) fancy:

```
OptionalInt maxVal = IntStream.range(0, playerCount).reduce((a, b) -> scores.get(a) > scores.get(b) ? a : b);
maxVal.ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("player " + (i+1) + " won with a final score of " + scores.get(i)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to work this into my code, do I need to initialize the linked list ?? Receiving error that it can't find symbol

Comment: @HaleyNewbold If you mean if it's necessary to call `= new LinkedList<>()`: Yes!

Comment: @HaleyNewbold I would recommend to copy the code as-is and then work your way backwards to your own solution. Then you'll see at which point it breaks :)

Comment: @HaleyNewbold you call it like its written in the answer :D `List<Integer> scores = new LinkedList<>();`. But think carfully if you want to copy this solution. Your teacher will know it's not your own ;)

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet? I can quickly post a solution using arrays

Comment: so sorry I did not reply sooner. You were a hugeeeee help and I appreciate your efforts. @Lonely

Comment: @HaleyNewbold and if you had replied in two weeks it would not have been too late ;)

Comment: @HaleyNewbold I am happy if it helped! Programming can be weird when you learn it for the first time, but I am sure you'll do great :D

Answer (score 0):

Considering result is your custom object it's contain marks.

First create object of comparator class like 
Comparator com= comparator.comparing(Result::getMarks);

Here getMarks is your getter method and mark is your variable.

Result result = List.s stream(). Max(com).get();

You can also find minimum value using min function..